# I tried deleting node_modules, package-lock.json and clearing NPM's cache, but I'm still getting ELIFECYCLE when I try to install "@keyv/sqlite"

Tags: node.js, npm

I have been getting NPM error code `ELIFECYCLE` for some time now, but deleting node_modules, package-lock.json and clearing npm's cache doesn't seem to be fixing it.

Here is my npm log: https://pastebin.com/AVxwAnCn (very sorry about 7000 or so lines)

Also, this error only seems to be happening for the "@keyv/sqlite" package!

Comment: This is the infamous "node-pre-gyp install" error. Here's the top of the rabbit hole to get you started: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/594. This isn't a problem with the SQLite package specifically but rather a problem with one of its dependencies.

Comment: Also, try to put the question in the title instead of your attempts to fix the problem.

Comment: @Bradley this I tried this with --fallback-to-build, like they suggested. but it didn't work, is there something else that would work to fix it?